# Found unsigned entry in resource ... .jar

Tags: netbeans, jar, java-web-start, sign

I'm using Netbeans to compile and sign all my jars, all with the same certificate. However, when I run Webstart with Sun Java SE 6, I get the error Found unsigned entry in resource .. .jar.

I messed around with adding and removing jars, etc, but no luck.

As far as I know the keystore is in the build directory and gets created on every *clean and build*.

It gives this error not for one jar, but multiple (switching orders of jars led me to believe this).

I'm using Netbeans 7. I booted Windows this morning and got the error, which I didn't have yesterdag or before.

I'm pulling my hair out, Webstart and the like is driving me crazy! Any help would be really appreciated.

Edit: The manifest files all look alright btw.

Edit: The jnlp looks fine as well, and didnt change any from before it broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling JAR caching should fix the problem. It's a common bug that exists in Java for *years*. For details, see my blogpost: 
https://www.nowaker.net/post/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource-java-web-start.html

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the pc again and it works again. Must've been something weird with the Java JRE or something...