# RDF-Gravity 1.0 - unable to launch the application

Tags: java, rdf, semantics, triplestore

I was trying to install RDF-Gravity 1.0 on Windows 7 x64bit machine. The installation failed with a message `Unable to launch the application`. The exception in the `Details/Exception`is provided below. I will be thankful to you, if any body knows how to get over it.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/jws/colt.jar
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.checkAllJarEntriesSigned(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://semweb.salzburgresearch.at/apps/rdf-gravity/jws/colt.jar
... 15 more
```

**Edited:** I have followed the useful comments by Joshua and they look promising. Since I do not have much knowledge about JNLP, I could not figure out "How to make the Java Web Start application working with disabled cache?". Alternatively, having gone through a blog for [rdf visualization tools](http://semanticscience.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/visualisation-of-ontologies-and-large-scale-graphs/), I have found something similar to RDF-Gravity called [welkin](http://simile.mit.edu/welkin/), which also visualizes RDF.

Comment: StackOverflow has [some questions about this error message "found unsigned entry in resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Found+unsigned+entry+in+resource%22+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Does this one, which mentions jar caching, help? [Found unsigned entry in resource … .jar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7182762/1281433).

Comment: Did one of those work for you?  If so, which one?

Comment: HI Joshua, thank you for trying to help me. The link to the solution seems promising. However, I am new to JNLP and could not figure out "How to make the Java Web Start application working with disabled cache?".

Comment: well, that's much more specific information now.  You should update your question so that people who can answer that sort of question might have a better chance of finding it.  (This isn't an area I'm very familiar with, so that's probably not me.)  Narrow down the problem (e.g., "how to start Java Web Application when cache is disabled"), gather all the relevant information that you can, and update the question.

Comment: I just received this same error.  Toggling temporary files caching in the Java Control Panel did not fix the problem.  Does anyone have this working?

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the Webstart version of RDF Gravity does no longer work on some systems is that the certificate for the colt.jar is no longer accepted by some JVM versions. For those who are interested in details [this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.distro-packaging.devel/12020) explains why this is the case.

People who are affected by that can download the RDF Gravity version available [here](http://www.salzburgresearch.at/~rwesten/rdf-gravity/rdf-gravity_20090302_rw.zip).  The "rdf-gravity.jar" contained in the zip archive is a runable jar.

best
Rupert

Comment: Amazing ! This is what I was looking for, great job, thank you. 
I downloaded your zip, extracted and run the 'rdf-gravity.jar', now it works like magic. Well done, Rupert.